# Chrome extension: AJAX returns php as comment line

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension on a localhost with an $.get request that executes a PHP script and echoes the output in a div. The PHP does execute and echo but inside the popup.html javascript returns the output as a comment.
Is it not possible to use php in any way in a chrome extension?

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="toolbox.js"></script>
  <head>
    <body>
      <div id="hello"></div>
    </body>
```

Toolbox.js:

```
$(function(){
   $.get('toolbox.php', function(data){
       $("#hello").html(data);
   });
});
```

toolbox.php:

```
<?php
  echo 'hello';
?>
```

result:

```
<div id="hello"><!--?php
  echo 'hello';
?--></div>
```

EDIT: I am running it in xampp the extension folder is in my htdocs folder and the php is inside the extension folder when i go to http://localhost/chrome%20extension/popup.html it does execute the php properly

Comment: If you're just hitting a PHP page without actually going through a webserver that is serving up the PHP, you're just going to get the file contents

Comment: The PHP *clearly* ***isn't*** executing.  Is this running on a webserver or on your local PC (`file:///`)?  Is the PHP file *part* of the extension or is it hosted on a *webserver*?

Comment: I am running it in xampp the extension folder is in my htdocs folder and the php is inside the extension folder when i go to http://localhost/chrome%20extension/popup.html it does execute the php properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like you are running this without a webserver and the php doesn't actually get executed - so you will need to setup one in order to make this work.

Once you've done this, have a look at [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which is made for what you are doing with `$.get()`:

```
$(function(){
   $("#hello").load('toolbox.html');
});
```

Comment: I am running it in xampp the extension folder is in my htdocs folder and the php is inside the extension folder when i go to http://localhost/chrome%20extension/popup.html it does execute the php properly